# Magento 2 How to Upload Image For Category Using Rest API?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, rest-api, magento2.4.4

I want to upload a Webp image for category using Rest API. i did the same thing for product with reference of product image upload API (that support image with jpg or png extension) that's provided by magento core. But i am unable to find the category image upload API (that support image with jpg or png extension) in Magento core.

**For reference** sharing the API that i have used for product image upload of magento core:

**rest/all/V1/products/{product_sku}/media**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use category API for your issues:

https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.2/#tag/categories/operation/catalogCategoryRepositoryV1SavePost